# Javascript - multidimensional array: declare all key names

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I got this multidimensional array:

```
artikel[29938] = ['jeans', 'blue', '77'];

alert(artikel[29938][1]);
```

it alerts `blue`

But what I want:

```
artikel[29938] = ['titel': 'jeans','color': 'blue','size': '77'];

alert(artikel[29938]['color']);
```

How to do that? Is it even possible? ^^

Comment: Ok :D How would you define my question?

Comment: I'd suggest carefully reviewing the difference between arrays (a list of elements, in square brackets), and objects (a set of `key: value` pairs, in curly brackets). This is covered well in any number of tutorials or intros.

Comment: I know array perfectly from PHP and there it's much less complicated, I wouldn't know the reason why such thing as object even exist?!

Comment: just replace the square brackets to curly brackets 

`artikel[29938] = {'titel': 'jeans','color': 'blue','size': '77'};`

Comment: Objects in JavaScript are like PHP's (unusual) "associative arrays." If you want an ordered collection of items with numeric keys (0, 1, 2, …), use an Array. If you want an unordered collection of items with string keys (`"foo"`, `"bar baz"`, `"123"`), use an Object.

Comment: Why do arrays exist in javascript in the first place? or better question: why aren't objects called arrays then and the useless crap isn't removed??

Comment: Objects are at the heart of JS. They exist as the fundamental way of holding data.

Comment: I try around with objects now, can you tell me what's wrong with: var artikel = {};
    artikel{
        "27":{"cid":"7","uid":"9"},
        "17":{"cid":"1","uid":"3"}
    };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var artikel = [
  {'title': 'jeans','color': 'blue','size': '77'},
  {'title': 'top','color': 'blue','size': '77'}
];

//fetch/retrieve values
console.log(artikel[0].title)
console.log(artikel[0].color)
console.log(artikel[0].size)

//Conversion
console.log(JSON.stringify(artikel))
```

Use an array of an object like following:-

```
artikel[29938] = {'title': 'jeans','color': 'blue','size': '77'};
alert(artikel[29938]['title']);
```

Comment: Isn't it a mix of array and object then? Can I convert the whole thing in json string then without problem? Thanks :D

Comment: @AnneSchwarz Please check updated Snippet.
Hope it will answer all your question :)

Comment: The consolelog shows: [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null oO

Comment: @AnneSchwarz where you are getting null. Can you post in your whole code

Comment: var artikel = [];
    artikel[29938] = {'title': 'jeans','color': 'blue','size': '77'};
    artikel[37494] = {'title': 'jeans2','color': 'blue2','size': '88'};

    console.log(JSON.stringify(artikel));

Comment: Arrays have sequential, numeric indexes. If you create an empty array and then add an item at index 29938, what do you expect there to be at indexes 0, 1, 2, 3, … 29937? (The answer, of course, is `null`.)

Comment: Why the f.. are arrays in javascript so crappy??? In PHP you can do much MUCH more with arrays and much easier. What do you suggest for my situation?

Comment: @AnneSchwarz Welcome to the world of JS dear :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Rather than going to array as an data structure you can opt for Json array/String. It would give you much flexibility.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "JSON array'. There are just JavaScript arrays. Anyway, he is already using an array. What is your alternative suggestion?

Comment: Considering OP's name and profile photo I'm guessing "he" isn't their preferred pronoun.